# Why is indicating one's exact address in an invoice important for tax reason?

Tags: taxes, united-kingdom, billing

I'm purchasing a license for a UK-based system software ([EasyChair](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EasyChair)). It says that indicating my exact address on the invoice is required for tax reason. What's the reason they're tax alluding to?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the UK, VAT "Full Invoice" is required for non-retail transactions. The customer's address is a [mandatory field](https://www.gov.uk/vat-record-keeping/vat-invoices) for "Full Invoice".

The website developer probably didn't spend time designing a separate logic for "zero-rated" VAT or exports.